# Print all possible strings of length k that can be formed from a set of n characters returns >n characters

Tags: python

Python novice here. The goal of the following Code is, to print all possible combinations to pair n characters of the set.
The Problem is that the following code gives an output, that also has more then n characters.

In the Following Code example n=3, but in the Output there are combinations with more then 3.

**Code**:

```
def printAllKLength(set, k): 
    n = len(set) 
    printAllKLengthRec(set, "", n, k) 

def printAllKLengthRec(set, prefix, n, k):
    if (k == 0) : 
        print(prefix) 
        return

    for i in range(n): 
        newPrefix = prefix + set[i]         
        printAllKLengthRec(set, newPrefix, n, k-1) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("First Test") 
    set1 = ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S','T','V','W','Y'] 
    k = 3
    printAllKLength(set1, k)
```

**Output:**

```
WNT
WNV
WNW
WNY
WPQA
WPQC
WPQD
WPQE
WPQF
WPQG
WPQH
WPQI
WPQK
WPQL
WPQM
WPQN
WPQPQ
WPQR
WPQS
WPQT
WPQV
WPQW
WPQY
WRA
```

The aim would be to generate strictly strings of length 3, so if anyone could point me in the right direction, I would be more than grateful.

Comment: This seems like homework but `itertools` has functions to do exactly this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote you functions a bit and stripped them to the essentials:

```
def printAllKLength(set, k):
    printAllKLengthRec(set, "", k)


def printAllKLengthRec(set, string, k):
    if len(string) == k:
        print(string)
        return

    for c in set:
        printAllKLengthRec(set, string + c, k)
    return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("First Test")
    set1 = ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K',
            'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'W', 'Y']
    k = 3
    printAllKLength(set1, k)
```

A little hint for next time, break you sample size down to for example `len(set1) = 3`. then it is far easier to debug and you don't get lost in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Itertools' combinations function. It takes an iterable and the length of the combination as parameters.

```
import itertools

num_char = 3
my_set = {'A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'W', 'Y'}
combinations = itertools.combinations(my_set, num_char)
for i in combinations:
    print("".join(i))
```

Comment: Thank you all for the help! I've previously used itertools, but it does not handle combinatorial explosion well (for example, when trying to print k=10).